# Hide Status Bar and Increase the height of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

I am using story board to create navigation bar.

My requirement is to hide the status bar and increase the height of Navigation bar. When i hide the status bar, the navigation bar sticks to top and the height is 44 px. i need a navigation bar height as 64 px (44px+status bar height). Is there any way to do this?

**With status bar**

[image]
**Without status bar**
[image: Without Status bar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start off, you hide your `statusBar` by following these steps:

First, put this code in `viewWillAppear`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Second, set your `info.plist` file as the below image shows:

[image]

Next, you can make a `Category` of `UINavigationBar` and in it set the height of the `navigaionBar`.

**Objective-c**

in .h file

```
@interface UINavigationBar (Custom)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size ;
```

and in .m file

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (Custom)

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, 100);
    return newSize;
}
```

**Swift**

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    public override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
        let newSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 64)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. i thought of this idea. but do i need to adjust y position all subviews in all view controller to 64px?

Comment: Not of allView ,only Navigation Subview.

Comment: where should i alloc the view. in viewdidload it's not working

Comment: Great. It works. But self.frame.size.width is not working. i harcoded 1024 for iPad. i implemented category as extension in swift.

Comment: how do i call it in swift? trying to get it work, but it always says: Use of instance member 'sizeThatFits' on type 'UINavigationBar'; did you mean to use a value of type 'UINavigationBar' instead?