# How can I change size of UINavigationBar in UINavigationViewController in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar

What is the proper way to change height of navigation bar?

I need to create custom title in navigation bar, it should contains two UILabels one above other. The Title should be resized to fit those UILabels.

Should I override `sizeThatFits`: method in my custom TitleView, would other buttons correctly change to fit that size? How can I change a size of NavigationBar?

That is what I need to create using latest SDK features.

[image]

Comment: add custom navigation bar..

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380873/hide-status-bar-and-increase-the-height-of-uinavigationbar/26381417#26381417

Comment: You can change height of Navigation Controller check above link.

Comment: @KiritModi sorry, but it is really bad way - to override method with category.

Comment: What about using the Prompt Property on the UINavigationItem?

Comment: Hacking around with the height of the navigation bar will cause you all kinds of funny issues. Trust me, I've been there and regret it.

Comment: The proper way is to NOT change the height of the navigation bar. (as they say in Human interface guidelines and documentation) However there are a lot of workarounds that can break at any moment and bring a lot of fun to your life :)

Comment: http://www.emdentec.com/blog/2014/2/25/hacking-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 3):

Create the following class category (you can create it in your implementation file):

```
#import "objc/runtime.h"

@interface UINavigationBar (CustomHeight)

- (void)setHeight:(CGFloat)height;

@end

static char const *const kHeight = "Height";

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomHeight)

- (void)setHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kHeight, @(height), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSNumber *)height
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kHeight);
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize newSize;

    if (self.height) {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(self.superview.bounds.size.width, [self.height floatValue]);
    } else {
        newSize = [super sizeThatFits:size];
    }

    return newSize;
}
@end
```

And after that, simply call `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHeight:100.0]` in your `viewDidLoad` or where you need it. Works in both iOS 7.1 and 8.1.

Disclaimer: Any alteration of the API and its functions is prone to future issues with new OS releases! Apple does not intend to allow us to change the navigation bar height (except for some rare instances) so use any solution wisely after assessing the risks vs advantages.

Comment: it is  a bad way to override methods in category

Comment: Who told you that? It's not a private api nor it's discouraged by Apple to extend a class. Where's the problem? You will not find a cleaner method than this. Only to add UI elements as someone mentioned below. But I agree with Alexander Tkachenko - Apple didn't gave us an easy way to do this for a reason. The navigation bar behavior can change dramatically over time. See what happened with the hack involving a Date Picker into an UIActionSheet when iOS 8 came out. A lot of apps started not working.

Comment: @codeFi There are indeed a few problems. Overriding an existing method in a category is *not* "extending" the class. It's completely replacing the existent implementation *without the possibility to call the original implementation* (thus your call to `super` does *NOT* call the implementation in UINavigationBar, but rather in `UIView`!). Secondly, you can't know if `UINavigationBar sizeThatFits:` is perhaps implemented in a category itself (which is often done in UIKit for separation of concerns). In that case it's undefined which of the two category implementations will be used at runtime!

Comment: @DanielRinser I agree with you but the behavior can change no matter what hack you could find. Don't you agree? Because let's face it: either way, to modify the height of the navbar is a hack because Apple doesn't allow this behaviour except in some very special cases. Heck! The behaviour can change even if you use the api as intended right now by Apple! So what are we talking about?

Comment: Hi guys, totally agree that it's bad to override method with category. But it's also wrong to hack the height of a UINavigationBar and category-hack is just a way to achieve the desired effect. As for the question about what implementation of sizeThatFits method will be executed by runtime, I think that category, created in source code will be linked later that UIKit's implementation(obviously), that's why our code will be called.

Comment: Right, but I just answered to "Who told you that? ... Where's the problem?". Many people are not aware of how categories work and just blindly copy stuff like this without knowing what's happening.. I didn't say that messing with the internals of standard UI components is good! ;-)

Comment: And you should also consider swizzling as an alternative, because then it's possible to call through to the original implementation.

Comment: @DanielRinser Oh, I see :D. I replied like that because I had the feeling that the OP knows exactly the implications of what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom view for both navigation title and navigation right bar button.

Here how you can add title view like above.

```
// Custom view for navigation title.
UIView *customTitleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 22)];
label1.text = @"Stasik";
label1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20];
label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[customTitleView addSubview:label1];

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 22, 100, 22)];
label2.text = @"Stasik iPhone";
label2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16];
label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label2.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[customTitleView addSubview:label2];

self.navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView;

// Custom view for right navigation.

UIButton *upButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
upButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 44);
[upButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[upButton addTarget:self action:@selector(upButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *upButtonBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:upButton];

UIButton *downButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
downButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 44);
[downButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[downButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *downButtonBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:downButton];

// Remove trailing space for right view.
UIBarButtonItem *nagativeSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
nagativeSpace.width = -11;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[nagativeSpace, upButtonBarItem, downButtonBarItem];

// Left item
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 44);
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Remove leading space for left view.
nagativeSpace.width = -15;

UIBarButtonItem *backButtonBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[nagativeSpace, backButtonBarItem];
```

OutPut:

[image]

Arrow images are different than OP's requirement but it serves layout for navigation views.

From above code make change in `nagativeSpace.width` value to arrange buttons with accurate distance from left as well as right margins.

Comment: There is no need to create a custom view for the two buttons on the right, just use `rightBarButtonItems` instead of `rightBarButtonItem`.

Comment: size of your title view is hard coded, it should be resized when title's strings are changed

Comment: @DanielRinser: Yes, you are right but if OP want some more specific arrangement of controls and space between it than it wold be good to go for customisation.

Comment: @BergP: This is a basic setup, there are lots of things which can comes in part a when requirement is there.

Comment: Sure, if a very custom thing is needed, that's a possibility. But here it doesn't seem to be necessary. Spacing (even "negative" spacing, i.e. reducing the default!) can be done by adding a `UIBarButtonItem` with system type `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace`.

Comment: @DanielRinser: Yes you are right. `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace `  will do the job.

Comment: @BergP: I have added more code for complete arrangement of views as your need. Have a look on edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that design that you posted, I don't have the impression that the bar is really higher than the standard 44pt. Please note that starting with iOS7 the status bar is integrated into the same bar and the 20pt of the status bar is added to the total height.

IMHO, the only problem you need to solve is to stack the title/subtitle, and that can be easily done with a custom `titleView`, as Kampai has demonstrated.