# Dynamically increase/decrease height of custom UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I followed this [blog post](http://www.emdentec.com/blog/2014/2/25/hacking-uinavigationbar) that explains how you can implement a custom `UINavigationBar` that has an increased height, if for example you wanted to put additional ui elements in the nav bar underneath the rest of the bar content that will persist between navigation on the stack. This code works really well in the case where you always want it to be that increased height.

In my app, I need to start the navigation bar at its default height, then increase it later, adding more content, after the user performs a given action. Very similar to the song info and controls in the iTunes Store:

[image]

So I put some checks in place to not reposition anything if a `BOOL` property is `NO`. When I set it to `YES`, I call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` which will call `layoutSubviews` to position everything appropriately based on that boolean value. `sizeThatFits` is also called and I return the proper height.

The problem is, I can't call `[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -(NavigationBarHeightIncrease))];` in `initialize`. Instead I call that at the same time I change the boolean value to `YES`. Because of this, all of my elements are moved up that amount. But if I don't call `setTransform`, the elements in the nav bar are in the proper position, but the bar itself is positioned too far down, so that the custom view I've added to the bar is shown overtop the view controller's view - it bleeds out, and the extra space I added is black not the navigation bar's background color.

If I call `setTransform` in `initialize`, when the height is the default height, the elements are moved up when they shouldn't be.

So, how can I properly dynamically change the height and positioning of a `UINavigationBar` subclass?

Comment: I would not recommend changing UINavigationBar-s height or its implementation at all , you never know what will be changed in UINavigationBar after next iOS release ,

Instead , I would use custom UIView , with the same background/style and attach it to the top layout guide , then you can manipulate your views easily without private-apis

Comment: @ogres Unfortunately I need this custom view to persist between push and pop operations, so I can't add it to a view controller's view - it needs to somehow be tied to the navigation controller/bar.

Comment: Why not create one RootView controller and then contain Navigation Controller inside it ? then you can maintain views

Comment: @ogres Maybe that's a solution. Just not sure how that'd work in practice, care to provide an answer on how you'd approach it?

Comment: I can give just an advice , but not truly an answer for your question , 

I have tried something like this , but only with UITabBarViewController , not sure if it works in UINavigation too , for example :

create UIViewController , 
create UINavigationViewController ( your current root view ) ,
in add UINavigationvc-s view as subview of uiviewcontroller , and uinavigationvc as childcontroller of uiviewcontroller , then see if it works , now you can add any view to UIViewcontroller and it will be available on all navigation pushes

Comment: @ogres While it would remain visible, I believe it would cover up the top of the navigation controller's top view controller. I also need it to disappear when the navigation bar disappears, or move up when the status bar is hidden, hence the reason I am trying to make it part of the nav bar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380873/hide-status-bar-and-increase-the-height-of-uinavigationbar/26381417#26381417

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, to achieve the behavior where a custom navigation bar (not subclassing the native control) persists across pushes and pops of controllers in a navigation controller, you'll need to have a single controller with the custom navigation bar and then a single embedded view that resolves to a `UINavigationController` with its view controllers underneath. Then, it will also be necessary to set the navigation controller's delegate to the root controller so that the title and other properties can be updated as the sub-controllers are pushed and popped. I've provided a screenshot below of what the storyboard version of this might look like:

[image: embedded navigation controller example]

Comment: I've set the delegate of the nav controller via `prepareForSegue` to `self`. I got rid of the top bar on the nav controller. But now how do I get the elements from my now hidden nav controller's nav bar into my custom nav bar? Only setting the delegate didn't do the trick.

Comment: You'll need to manage the titles manually. Using the existing data in the navigation bar such as `navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title` to get the current title, you can set the UI elements in your custom navigation view. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I can kind of get this to work setting the left/right bar button items and title in `navigationController:willShowViewController:`, but the swipe back gesture doesn't work, and the back button does not appear on the custom nav bar. Additionally since the nav bar starts at the top layout guide it doesn't reach under the status bar, so there's just white underneath the status bar.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to design as much or as little as you want for this custom view in order to get the height change desired. It's going to be tricky if you're wanting *all* the functionality of a navigation controller. If its allowable in your design constraints, I would make the navigation look a bit different and not mirror the native UI in every way. My post is to simply put you on the right track. For more information, I would google for creating a custom navigation bar.

Comment: I see. The problem is I need the exact same native navigation bar and behavior, with only another 'bar' shown underneath it. A custom nav bar isn't really what I'm after here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is might your best option if you really need to adjust the height of the navigation bar with an additional custom view.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create a UIViewController in storyboard which has only the control view you wish to show below the navigation bar with everything else transparent. The advantage here is you design this using the normal tools. Use constraints to place it just below the navigation bar and to set the heights, widths etc of your views.

When you wish to show the control, you can create an instance of this UIViewController and remove the content view from it and add it to the view hierarchy of what is on screen.

There are two options for inserting the extracted base view:

1. If you add this control view to the view controller at the top of
   the navigation stack (what is on screen), it would be covered when
   you push on a new controller. This is not what you said you wanted.
2. If you add this control view to self.navigationController.view, then
   it will persist across pushes and pops. This is what you said you wanted.

I use this approach to provide popup help bubbles to describe what is on screen. Depending on whether I use option 1 or 2, I can persist help across multiple pushes/pops.

I got the idea from this tutorial which describes the general approach: http://blog.typpz.com/2013/12/09/ios-sdk-create-a-pop-up-window/

That link provides a full code example on how to bring up the view and remove the view.

This would let you design it in IB, present and dismiss it as required and persist it across navigation sequences.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting approach. The only problem I see with this is that it will cover up the underlying views. I need the view controller(s) underneath to have their content insets adjusted, or the entire view moved down, so that the new view doesn't cover up their content.

Comment: @Joey An option is to create your tables as a UIViewController containing a UITableView rather than using a UITableViewController. You can then pin the top of the UITableView to the top layout guide with a constraint and an offset. When you want the overlay, change the constraint in code. As you have a constraint for the overlay and the table you can animate both in. Putting the overlay behind the nav bar (add overlay to front rather than end of nav view controller content view), you would see the overlay slide down from under the bar and the table slide down together.

Comment: @Joey Or even simpler add a blank row at the top of the table which is the same height as the overlay and reload 8^).

Comment: That would work if I were only using a single view controller, but once I push a different one, that won't have a constraint against the custom nav bar so it's content will be covered up.

Comment: @Joey Correct. You would need a mechanism so that any controller can find when the overlay is in place and in its `viewWillAppear` take the necessary steps to push the top down. I guess with going for extending the Nav Bar you had assumed the Top Layout Guide would do this part for you automatically which is an advantage.

Comment: Right. Then all of the controllers would have to readjust once that extra nav UI disappears. If I could make the actual nav bar adjust that would be much cleaner.

Comment: This looks useful: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Unfortunately none of those customizations persist between push/pop operations.

Comment: @Joey Are you sure that is the case. If you set the UINavigationBar to be your subclass,  then that is the navigation bar which will be used across all pushed/popped controllers. It is only the UINavigationItem which changes. So in that link if you just use CustomNavigationBar. It would be an easy try: Just implement `sizeThatFits` and make the bar bigger and see if it remains like that over pushes and pops which I think it will. Then you just need a toggle on that class to add/remove your views as required. Might need to call `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` to get it to redisplay.

Comment: You're correct, and that's exactly what I already tried and explained in my question. I can get the height to increase but that adds space above the elements, when I need everything positioned the same with a view added underneath. Attempting to dynamically reposition elements is where I encountered the trouble, and caused me to post this question.

Comment: @Joey I notice part 2 of that blog is missing with the final result. Unless I missed the link to it? The translation piece seems a bit of a hack, but I assume that works as far as making the height bigger is concerned. Being a translation, it will apply to everything which is probably what is going wrong. All I can suggest is a hybrid approach. Use blog part 1 to create the space with the buttons translated back then use an overlay at the right position as a sub view of the UINavigationController rather than adjusting the nav bar view itself. Hope you find a better option.