# How to change the navigation bar height

Tags: ios, objective-c

I saw a solution to change the height of navigation bar. But nothing worked for me. Now my application has one view controller connected with a navigation controller. I have not yet implemented any other code in my project. Before starting my project I need to change my height of my navigation bar.

edited:

.h:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size ;
```

.m:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customNav)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(370,40);
    return newSize;
}
@end
```

Comment: see this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380873/hide-status-bar-and-increase-the-height-of-uinavigationbar/26381417#26381417

Comment: see link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133257/iphone-how-set-uinavigationbar-height

Comment: but the width is showing for half size only.......for height is ok!..but how to set the width height that will equall for all 5,5s,6,6s,6+,6s screens

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894985/change-uinavigationbar-height

Comment: @RahulMishra  i tried that height is working but my width is differing for all screen

Comment: Hows that is possible ? are you using autolayouts ?

Comment: @user5737947 is their any problem using your own view instead of default navigation bar ?

Answer (score 2):

```
UIView *NavView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width , 44)];
NavView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
NavView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:NavView];

UIButton *DateBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 90, 30)];
DateBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[DateBtn setTitle:@"Jan 05" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
DateBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:BrushScriptStd size:18];
[DateBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[NavView addSubview:DateBtn];
```

Comment: while adding your solution should i connect with navigation controller or not with my viewcontroller

Comment: Yes you need to  connect with navigation controller

Comment: see my updated post i have tried that but only width is differing for all screen

Comment: One more solution you need to hide your navigation on your controller then add custom view

Comment: only bar button is adding..no navigation bar height changing.....i copy and past only

Comment: Dear in this cash you need to hide navigation bar and add custom view

Comment: if i hide my navigation bar then how your code will work.... see this line    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:NavView];

Comment: @user5737947 in that case add add the `NavView` to your ViewController. i.e. [self.view addSubView:NavView];

Answer (score 0):

You can not change UINavigation height but you can add you custom view on UINavigation bar

Comment: can you give me some code explain ...bez i have many screen which are connected with navigation bar.....so how can i add custom view to set for all screen and also i am having some title and bar button item.

Comment: UIView *NavView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width , 44)];
    NavView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    NavView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:NavView];

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution to this problem is you can create `view` from StoryBoard or from Code.

And add the view to your viewController.

You have to disable default navigation Bar from you project. You can do it by Storyboard also. Select your navigation bar and change the Status Bar to none:

[image]

And If you want to do via code then in your `didFinishLaunching` wirte this code:

```
UIStoryboard *tStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    RootVC* RootVCObj = [tStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootVC"];

    UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:RootVCObj];
    navC.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

After this add as many as Buttons to your view

> Main cons of this is that you have to make custom view for all Screens you currently have

Comment: Any solution please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251141/swipe-left-or-right-to-load-the-view-controller-with-the-collection-view-cell-hi