# Custom NavigationBar height with TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

I use a custom height for the NavigationBar:

```
extension UINavigationBar {
  override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 7)
  }
}
```

I also use a TabBar but when I press the more button to edit the bar, the height should be normal, because then the edit button cannot be pressed:

[image]

How can I specify a custom height of the NavigationBar just for some ViewControllers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380873/hide-status-bar-and-increase-the-height-of-uinavigationbar/26381417#26381417

Answer (score 0):

To do so you need to add in the view controller of custom NavigationBar height:

```
var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar()

func setNavBarToTheView() {
    self.navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)  // Here you can set you Width and Height for your navBar
    self.navBar.backgroundColor = (UIColor.blackColor())
    self.view.addSubview(navBar)
}
```

Reference to my answer: [Changing the height of the Navigation bar iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142375/changing-the-height-of-the-navigation-bar-ios-swift)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my app it adds a second NavigationBar. Is there a way to edit the original NavigationBar and not to add a new one?